# What do I have to do to get "The Greatest" achievement?

Tags: football-manager-2013

The description is only "become the greatest manager of all time" on Steam, which is not that descriptive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`The Greatest - You have become the greatest manager of all-time!` achievement is achieved by becoming, you guessed it, the greatest manager of all time.

There is a `Hall of Fame` in the game and you get points based on the competitions you have won. For example, the World Cup garners the most points (for a single competition). When you set at the top of this Hall of Fame, you will get the achievement.

You can find an (incomplete) list of the number of points accrued for competition wins [here](http://footballmanagerwiki.co.uk/index.php?title=Hall_of_Fame_points)